# Automatically firing base class functions

Tags: c#

I want to ask this question because of some safety mechanism for my code.
This may seem like useless, but it already made me lose much time debugging.

```
public class AnimalClass
{
    virtual void Mod{}
    virtual void UpdateSomeValues{} 
}
public class CatClass : AnimalClass
{ 
    override void Mod{}
    override void UpdateSomeValues{}
}
```

Is there a way in C# to automatically fire up `Cat`'s `UpdateSomeValues` function whenever `Cat`'s `Mod` function is called (without having to call it manually from `Cat`'s `Mod` function)?

And if possible, make it the same for all derived classes?

Answer (score 2):

No. You could solve that issue by introducing another, protected method that derived classes can override, and make the public one call into it once all the necessary processing is done:

```
public class AnimalClass
{
    public void Mod() 
    {
        // do stuff
        ModImpl();
    }
    protected virtual ModImpl() {}
}
```

With that derived classes would implement `ModImpl()` if they want to do some extra processing, and you're sure that `// do stuff` still happens when `Mod` is called.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I guess Like I thought, there is not a way to do that in the base class.